# Getting user entered password in hook function in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I want to get user details like username and password which is entered by user in `My account` page and admin user edit page also. In my custom module, I am using `mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL)` hook function.

How to get user entered username and password details when user form submits?? If this function is not correct then from which hook function can I get user details?

Answer (score 0):

$account->name has the account name reliably.
The password is encrypted in the user table, and so the only place you'd be able to see it is when the user creates their account or changes their password. In that case, you'll need to pull it from $edit.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But i want the password which is not present in the database, i want the password which is entered by the user when user form filled. Is mymodule_user() hook function is correct for this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your value lies on the $edit for the $op login and edit .
You could also hook_form_()alter these forms and on your submit handler, the value you are looking for is in the $form_state array